# Creating plots in R with 3 variables

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dataframe

I had been following the analysis steps in the [Little Book of R](http://little-book-of-r-for-multivariate-analysis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/multivariateanalysis.html). It is a great tutorial but for things to work, it and many other tutorials need to have the data organized a certain way.

My data is structured like this (a very tiny tiny sample)a:

```
Phylum Confidence Time Seq_ID Environment Dataset
Acidobacteria 0.801 5 >3134898 Marine 4440037.3
Bacteroidetes 0.812 6 >3066473 Marine 4440037.3
Acidobacteria 0.828 5 >3085551 Gut 4440038.3
Firmicutes    0.830 4 >3087676 Coral 4440036.3
```

I want a good way to

a) Plot the Time by bacterial phylum for each environment. I realize that this means I will need to created a plot for each phylum. (see [plots](http://errtemp.tumblr.com/))

b. Plot the time by environment of two different phyla which I will then color code by environment. (see [plots](http://errtemp.tumblr.com/))

I know I can create a new dataframe based on an environment and bacteria, but I have not been able to incorporate it correctly into a plot that uses a third variable (time).

```
new_df = myDF[(myDF$Environment=='Marine') & (myDF$Phylum=='Acidobacteria'),]
```

I have tried several things...

```
p <- ggplot(myDF, aes(Environment, Time))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Environment))
```

It creates a plot, but this does not take into consideration the phylum (e.g. I would like a separate plot for each phylum).

Or this...

```
 for (i in environment) #this is a list I created
 {
     for (j in phyla) #this is a list I created
     {
        #stats_df = myDF[(myDF$Environment==i) & (myDF$Phylum==j),]
        plot(myDF[[j]], myDF[[i]], xlab=NULL, ylab='Time')
      }
 }
```

This one gets errors

```
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
Calls: plot -> plot.default -> localWindow -> plot.window
Execution halted

shell returned 1
```

But even if it did plot, it still does not take into consideration the Time variable. What I am really trying to figure out is how to use three variables in a plot.

Comment: Can you please clarify the structure of your data sets and which plots you wish to produce. In the second plot, what seems to be name of phyla (sensu the second data set) appear as numerical variables. The first variable in the first data set (Phylum) has values that looks like the 'Environment' variable in the second data set.

Comment: Sure Henrik. I cleaned up the post.

Comment: Can you please show us the plotting code you have tried. [Questions asking for code should include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming phylum is a factor variable

```
library(ggplot2)
g<- ggplot(myDF, aes(Environment, Time))
g + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ phylum)
```

[image]

```
 library(ggplot2)

 g<- ggplot(df1, aes(Environment, Time))
 g + geom_point() + facet_grid(phylum ~ .)
```

[image]

Please see [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html) for the details.

Comment: Thank you, that has gotten me closer. I am dealing with ~40 different phyla and 20 environments. This approach will make a tight-fitting plot. I will keep reading, but thank you regardless.

Comment: Could you accept this as an answer if it does what are you looking for?

Comment: Your response - while helpful (thank you) does not quite do what I want (see links to plots). I am still wresting with other approaches. If in the end, your response does what I need (with some tinkering) that I will race to that big check mark, and slap it down on the table like it is a domino.

Comment: My answer was based on your sample data presented in your problem where you asked " I would like a separate plot for each phylum". I am unsure of what you really want with your real data. So, I can't help you on that. :)

Comment: Fair enough. Your response is to the spirit, but not the letter. However, I kept editing my question so much of the specific stuff was taken out. So how do you  know what the letter is?! I will give you the check mark and I will continue trying to get something like this to work...matplot(myDF[(myDF$Environment=="Acidobacteria") & (myDF$Phylum=="Marine"),], myDF$Time, type="p", xlab=NULL, ylab="test"). Thank you @Metrics.